# dependsOnGroups sequential order-Testng

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

when I tried to execute this below code,  I am confused with the order of Test Methods E and A.

My Output order is C->D->E->A->B

```
public class Example5 
{

    @Test
    public void A()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    @Test(dependsOnGroups={"MM"})
    public void B()
    {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    @Test(groups={"MM"})

    public void C()
    {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
    @Test(groups={"MM"})
    public void D()
    {
        System.out.println("D");
    }
    @Test
    public void E()
    {
        System.out.println("E");
    }
}
```

From the output, I can see Test Methods C and D got executed before B method(this I can understand), but what I don't understand is the sequential order of E and A methods.

Please explain how TestNG follows sequential order in this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<suite name="Suite-A">
<test name="test">
    <classes >
        <class name="stack1.LoginTest"></class>
        <methods>
            <include name="A" />
            <include name="E" />
            <include name="B" />
            <include name="C" />
            <include name="D" />
        </methods>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Use this suite to run where methods are explicitly mentioned in the class. And you can see the out put as `A > E > C > D > B` .
I guess this is what you are expecting to see.

If you want to set the order in code, you can use `@Test( priority = 1 )` for your methods. Lower priorities will be scheduled first. So for example -2 will execute before 1.

If you want to preseve order for multiple classes, use `group-by-instances="true"` in the testng.xml suite.

---

> Related Stackoverflow Links:
>
> - [Priority in TestNG with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632241/)
> - [Order of execution of tests in TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669576/)
> - [Run TestNG tests in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648229/)
>
> [Cedric's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162410/cedric-beust) Blog:
>   http://beust.com/weblog/2008/03/29/test-method-priorities-in-testng/
>
> TestNG document:
>  http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html