# Randomizing TestNG Invocations

Tags: unit-testing, testing, testng

Similar to: [Run TestNG tests in random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648229/run-testng-tests-in-random-order) but different as this question does not include invocations.

TestNG randomizes the tests themselves but the invocations will all run in a row. For Example:

@Test(invocation=2) public void A{}
@Test(invocation=2) public void B{}

will either run AABB or BBAA
but I was hoping to have them run in a truly random manner (ABAB, BABA, ect)

Is there anyway to accomplish this with TestNG, at the moment all I can think of is changing my tests to methods called by one test that controls the order but I hoping for something built in to TestNG that I overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build on the same concept of leveraging a IMethodInterceptor.

Here's how you do it.
First you build a custom annotation that can be used to express the invocation count.

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;

@Retention(java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface InvocationCount {
    int value() default 1;
}
```

You now customize your method interceptor such that it looks up the custom annotation and based on it, it adds up more instances and then eventually randomizes the resultant collection.

```java
import org.testng.IMethodInstance;
import org.testng.IMethodInterceptor;
import org.testng.ITestContext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class LocalInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {

    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        List<IMethodInstance> altered = new ArrayList<>();
        for (IMethodInstance method : methods) {
            InvocationCount count = method.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(InvocationCount.class);
            if (count == null) {
                altered.add(method);
            } else {
                if (count.value() > 1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < count.value(); i++) {
                        altered.add(method);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(altered, new Random(seed));
        return altered;
    }
}
```

Your test would now look like below

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Listeners(LocalInterceptor.class)
public class SampleTestClass {

    @InvocationCount(2)
    @Test
    public void A() {
        System.err.println("A()");
    }

    @InvocationCount(3)
    @Test
    public void B() {
        System.err.println("B()");
    }
}
```

Here's a sample output (There were some `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exceptions from the reporters, but I think that's not related to this)

```
...
... TestNG 6.14.2 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
B()
A()
B()
B()
A()
PASSED: B
PASSED: A
PASSED: B
PASSED: B
PASSED: A

===============================================
    48715503_test
    Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
48715503_Suite
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```