# preserve-order="false" not working in Test NG

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am trying to run my tests in random order using `preserve-order="false"`

However, the tests still run in the sequential order as opposed to the random order.

SimpleTest code:
[image]

SimpleTest1 Code:
[image]

SimpleTest3 Code:
[image]

And testng2 XML Code:
[image]

Comment: Check is this your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648229/run-testng-tests-in-random-order